# How to set stationary transform of a game object to a moving transform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ledge grab system with hanging. Player then has 2 options: to climb or to let go. However, I don't know a way to reset the transform from the one I've got set to hold to a ledge. The player would be falling so I don't know the exact vector because it would be changing.

I use **dropLedge** boolean to cancel the ledge holding and let the player fall.

Here is my ledge holding code:

```
private void LedgeHold()
    {
        dropLedge = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S);   
        if(ledgeDetected == true && canClimbLedge == false)
        {
            holdGrab = true;
            if(isFacingRight)
            {
                ledgePos1 = new Vector2(Mathf.Floor(ledgePosBot.x + wallCheckDistance) - ledgeClimbXOffset1, Mathf.Floor(ledgePosBot.y) + ledgeClimbYOffset1);
            }
            transform.position = ledgePos1;     
            canMove = false;

            if(holdGrab == true && dropLedge == true)
            {
                holdGrab = false;
                canFlip = true;
                canMove = true;
            }
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want to go back to the position you were before you set it with `transform.position = ledgePos1;`. Before doing this, store the value of `transform.position` temporarily.

Set the `transform.position` back to the temp variable when the player lets go.

Comment: Well that was simple enough to let my overthinking create a problem over it. Thank you!